# Mysql how to group by each day between two dates?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query which returns sum of one field for some id between two dates. How can I group the result for each of those days ?

Here is the query.

```
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(r.distance),r.* FROM ROUTES r 
        WHERE DATE(r.endRoute) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
        AND r.car_id = '.$request->getParam('id').'
        GROUP BY (each of now - interval ???)';
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to extract the date part in the `group by` clause too:

```
SELECT   DATE(r.endRoute), SUM(r.distance)
FROM     routes r 
WHERE    DATE(r.endRoute) > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND r.car_id = '.$request->getParam('id').'
GROUP BY DATE(r.endRoute)
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is working , i dont know why but i was thinking that is going to be a lot harder... :)